# Ошибка Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost

Я новичок, пишет, что ошибка в 7 строке, подскажите как исправить!

```
        <p> Категория: 
        <select name="catid">
            <?php 
                foreach ($cats as $cat)
                {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $cat['id']?>" <?php
                        if ($cat['id']==$catid)
                            echo " selected";
                    ?>><?php echo $cat['name']?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: вы только сам факт ошибки видите в сообщении, или еще и текст можете понять который там написан? Скорее всего там и имя переменной это указано? catid, например.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому, что ошибка именно в 7 строке, а не в 6 - то не определена именно переменная $catid, а не $cat['id'], которая появляется еще в 6 строке.
Переменная $catid не задана ранее, поэтому сравнивать значение $cat['id'] не с чем.